# How do you add a generic View to the LibraryContentPrivider

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

So I have a view that takes another view as a parameter and wraps that view in a wrapper with some additional data around it:

```
struct GenericRow<Content: View>: View {

var child: Content
var mileage: String

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(mileage)
            .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
        Spacer()
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            self.child
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 8)
    .frame(width: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
}
```

Ive added a class with the following to add it to the Library:

```
struct Generic_Library: LibraryContentProvider {
    var views: [LibraryItem] {
        return [
            LibraryItem(GenericRow<Text>(child: Text("Text"), mileage: "20k"), title: "Generic Maintenance Row", category: .control),
        ]
    }
}
```

Other items that I've created and added to this array show up, but I seem to be having issues with this one specifically. I can't seem to find much online about implementing generic views, since it is a relatively new feature. The view itself seems to work properly in the preview, so im guessing that my implementation of the library item is wrong, but im not sure how because im not getting any errors.

Comment: What is `LibraryItem` and `MaintenanceRow`? It's not declared in your code. We could guess, but it's best to be explicit

Comment: Sorry, I renamed and forgot to change it in the library. I'll correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solution is actually easier than I thought, removing the generic definition below fixed it:

```
struct Generic_Library: LibraryContentProvider {
    var views: [LibraryItem] {
        return [
            LibraryItem(GenericRow(child: Text("Text"), mileage: "20k"), title: "Generic Maintenance Row", category: .control),
        ]
    }
}
```